# ActionBarCompat, supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) and expected behavior

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I'm uncertain of the expected behavior when using ActionBarCompat and supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE). I see two different behaviors depending on Android version:

- On a Android ICS (possibly also from Android 3.0?) device using ActionBarCompat a call to supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) would hide the combined titlebar/actionbar
- On a Android 2.3 device the actionbar is still visible even though supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) is called.

Some additional information: My activities extend android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity and my app uses the @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light theme. supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) is called before setContentView(). I never make any call to either getSupportActionBar().show() or hide().

So, what's the expected behavior? When I used ABS a call to requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) would hide the titlebar/actionbar regardless of Android version.

How would I go about having an android app where some activies use an actionbar while others have none? Should they not extend the same base class?

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a solution to this but it uses styles applied via the AndroidManifest (and therefore needs no code). Keep in mind that this will almost definitely only work if you're using the [AppCompat library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat).

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="..."
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <activity
            android:label="@string/log_in"
            android:name=".activities.LogInActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/sign_up"
            android:name=".activities.SignUpActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Note how I've got a global theme applied directory to the `<application>` tag, and then also a theme that's individually applied to my `MainActivity` class through its own `<activity>` tag. That is the only Activity where I want the Action Bar to be hidden; everywhere else I want it to be visible (which is why I don't have individual themes applied to any of my other Activities as I instead let them inherit from the global application theme).

But you'll quickly find that `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` doesn't actually exist. This is because I had to create that style myself, which requires two different `styles.xml` files:

### values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

### values-v11/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You must use two different `styles.xml` files for this as the `android:windowActionBar` flag didn't exist before [Android API version 11](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels).